# Entity Framework Core will not map to BigInteger

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am needing to use the `BigInteger` class to handle large integers to my classes, however when trying to use EntityFramework Core to map to a DB table I recieve the following error:

> The property `AllianceRank.Reputation` could not be mapped, because
>   it is of type `BigInteger` which is not a supported
>   primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map this
>   property, or ignore it.

```
[Column("reputation")]
public BigInteger Reputation { get; set; }
```

It would seem that `BigIntegers` are not a supported type for mapping. How can I force it to map, or otherwise resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

Entity Framework would have to make assumptions about how to store that. If you're using SQL server, for example, `bigint` doesn't work because your values could be larger or smaller than what's possible with `bigint`. Would `varchar` be more appropriate? Possibly, but if you truly mean it to be a number and not say, an identifier, asking EF to query that as a number is going to be problematic. So essentially, there are less ambiguous types like `long` or `string` where you're not leaving the guesswork on how to store it up to Entity Framework.

Comment: EF would have to make assumptions, but those don't throw the error I posted above. It does not stop me from using a `long` with an `INT(3)`, which it would be unable to store, and would throw an `out of bounds` error upon execution if the long was large enough. Moving to a `varchar` does not address the EF issue itself, especially since I am doing math on the columns in my queries. The error implies I can explicitly direct it to map to the BigInteger, how can I do that?

Comment: How are you planning to represent BigInteger in your SQL?

Comment: I am representing it as an `INT(25)` right now in MySQL. Currently this successfully maps to a `long` even though the `long` does not support numbers that large. Issues with large ints only come into play at the time of the mapping if the number is too large, and only then.

Answer (score 4):

Since EF Core 2.1, you can define [Value Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions) when you define data models in the `OnModelCreating()` function of your `DbContext` class.

The best part is that this allows property values to be converted **automatically** when reading from or writing to the database!

So, in your case, you have a `BigInteger` property (`Reputation`) in C# and a corresponding `INT(25)` field in MySQL, you can do this:

```
var converter = new ValueConverter<BigInteger, long>(    
    model => (long)model,
    provider => new BigInteger(provider));

modelBuilder
    .Entity<AllianceRank>()
    .Property(e => e.Reputation)
    .HasConversion(converter);
```

P.S. You might actually wanna use a variable-length `string` type (like VARBINARY) to store the value in MySQL instead of `INT(25)`, as a C# `BigInteger` store a much larger value and therefore cause exceptions while converting to `INT(25)` or C# `long`.

Comment: This is the correct answer here thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Only scalar types, string, and byte[] are supported.
The largest scalar type available is decimal. Which "only" allows 28-29 significant digits.

Comment: Thank you, however, how can I fix the issue? Entity Framework can definitly map to classes. How do I explicitly direct it to map to a BigInteger?

Comment: You can do explicit mapping as discussed here.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505056/if-i-dont-explicitly-map-a-column-in-code-first-ef-to-an-existing-db-will-that. But still you will get an error if you map big int

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
public long FieldName { get; set; }
```

In your Model class, it will be `bigint` datatype in SQL

Comment: This has nothing with c#'s `BigInteger` struct.

Answer (score 0):

For the poor souls who receive this cryptic error message in a similar situation:

*Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.Decimal'.*

You would assume that Entity Framework would automatically map a SQL Server bigint (64 bit unsigned integer) to the appropriate C# long (also 64 bit unsigned integer), but noo...

So, you have to provide a bit of guidance, in the OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelbuilder) method of your DbContext, using **HasColumnType()**, like so:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Some.Namespace
{
    public class YourClassDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public YourClassDbContext(DbContextOptions<YourClassDbContext> options) : base(options) 
        {
        }

        public YourClassDbContext() {}

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            /* omitted stuff for PK and index */
            modelBuilder.Entity<ClassXYZ>().Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnType("long");
            
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
```

With many thanks to @Kelvin Lai above, whose answer put me on the right path, and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions

Answer (score 0):

my problem solved by :
by use int64 instead of biginteger

```
public class MyClassName
    {
        [Key]
        public Int64 TableId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: An `Int64` is a `long`, which is not a `BigInteger`. This would not solve the problem since this defeats the purpose of using a `BigInteger`, which is to handle numbers too large for a `long`.

Comment: In other words: *your* problem solved, not that in the question. Hence: not an answer.

Comment: hi. I Used public Int64 TableId { get; set; }   and table created by ef core : Bigint field in Sql Database

Comment: That's beside the point. The question is about c#'s `BigInteger` struct. Your answer has nothing to do with that. And, BTW, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68136207/861716) is the same answer.